# regex ensure string starts with

Tags: javascript, regex

I need a regex that will ensure the the user input looks like this "auth+live+xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx' Where x is alpha numeric so I got the alpha numeric done like so

```
/^[a-z0-9]+$/i
```

How do I ensure that input starts with auth+live+ ?

any help would be greatly appreciated

Comment: The question seems obvious.  They want a regex that matches this: `auth+live+xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx`.

Comment: Does it need to limit the number of alpha numeric characters to 40, like the example?

Comment: yes it does but i was just gonna use i different function for that but I suppose it might be better to make it all one validation

Comment: edited post to clearly state the question

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I think this does what you're asking for:

```
/^auth\+live\+[a-zA-Z0-9]+$/
```

Comment: @Truth - my answer is different than yours.  I thought the OP wanted a a capitalization match on the leading two words.

Answer (score 4):

How about

```
/^auth\+live\+[a-z0-9]+$/i
```

Comment: +1 - what does the trailing `i` do?  (I've had the pleasure of avoiding regexes for the most part :)  )

Comment: @AdamRackis: Case insensitivity. :)

Comment: @amnotiam - thank you - I seem to remember learning that at some point now :)